# Error with Report Page in Oracle Application Express

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

[image]I have a report based on a SQL Query, the report has 3 columns from v$session.

```
select distinct to_char(SQL_EXEC_START, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI') TIME_STARTED, module REPORT_NAME, action CURRENT_STEP from v$session where module like '%BOB%'
```

In SQL Developer, the query brings up what you would expect. However in the APEX report page, no matter what is in v$session, I always get (in addition) the following displayed at the top of the report page, in the actual report columns:

```
<DATE>  Processes - point: BEFORE_BOX_BODY  BOB01/APEX:APP 104:7
```

Can anyone tell me how to get rid of it, and simply output the query results into the report page, and nothing else?

Comment: I'm having trouble visualising this - can you attach a screenshot?

Comment: @Scott I've spent some time seeing how I do that - apparently you cannot add images to comments... :-/

Comment: @Scott Thanks I edited the question to add the picture... should be able to see what I mean now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it displays current report as well. So - remove it, e.g.

```
select distinct 
  to_char(SQL_EXEC_START, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI') TIME_STARTED, 
  module REPORT_NAME, 
  action CURRENT_STEP 
from v$session 
where module like '%BOB%'
  -- add this
  and module not like '%104:7%'
  and current_step not like '%BEFORE_BOX_BODY%'
```

Comment: Perfect. Guess I should have realised... it threw me that from a normal SQL client I wasn't getting the extra data returned, but then I wasn't running a normal SQL client session - Fixed it, appreciate it thank you.